# Overriding "SSL client : No" for a specific nginx vitual server

Tags: nginx, certificate-authority, client-certificate

I have a bunch of clients (too many to easily retrofit) each holding a single certificate (signed by a non-standard CA over which I have no control; I just generated the CSRs).

Now I need to setup a "secured" web service where server is identified in the usual ssl (https) way and client should be identified using its certificate (Subject is already holding all info I need to uniquely identyfy client).

Unfortunately in the signing process almost all "purpose" flags have been cleared:

```
openssl x509 -in 57EMM020001.cer -noout -purpose 
Certificate purposes:
SSL client : No
SSL client CA : No
SSL server : No
SSL server CA : No
Netscape SSL server : No
Netscape SSL server CA : No
S/MIME signing : Yes
S/MIME signing CA : No
S/MIME encryption : No
S/MIME encryption CA : No
CRL signing : No
CRL signing CA : No
Any Purpose : Yes
Any Purpose CA : Yes
OCSP helper : Yes
OCSP helper CA : No
Time Stamp signing : No
Time Stamp signing CA : No
```

I assume "culprit" for "400 The SSL certificate error" is the first one: "SSL client : No".

Is there any way to tell my local nginx server (over which I have full control) to disregard these settings?

I fully understand this is "bad" in general because if a certificate was not generated for a specific purpose... well, it shouldn't be used for that purpose! but this is my, very specific, server and I feel I'm entitled to decide who I trust.

Is there some way to convince nginx to do things in a slightly looser way?

My current (not working) setup is quite simple:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    resolver 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8;
    set $backend "http://localhost:5000";

    server_name updates.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/CAroot.cer;
    ssl_verify_client on;

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   60;
        proxy_read_timeout      60;
        proxy_send_timeout      60;
        proxy_intercept_errors  off;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Client-Subject   $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }    
}
```

Of course I checked that:

```
openssl verify -verbose -CAfile /etc/ssl/certs/CAroot.cer 57EMM020001.cer 
57EMM020001.cer: OK
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How will you also configure every web browser in the world to ignore the bad certificate? There is no way to do it. You need to get the CA fixed.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: That's not needed nor wanted. This is needed to implement a RESTful API between some (20k+) embedded targets and a single server (essentially for updating purposes). Requests are placed by a python client (no browser involved at all) and served by a python/flask backend (nginx used for reverse proxy). Please see answer I posted for whoever may have similar problems; if You can come up with a more elegant solution I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: If you control all the clients then yes, you can make it work. Others who read this question because they have a similar issue might not be so fortunate. Maybe someone is able to find another answer, but fixing the misbehaving CA is still a good idea.

Comment: It surely is a good idea, but utterly unfeasible as this specific CA is State owned and I hav e NO way to even ask for a fix. I'm actually trying to use a certificate meant to be used in validating reporting to said State Agency for a completely different purpose (receive trusted software updates). Rationale behind this is that certificate is already securely installed on targets and recalling 20k+ machines for refurbishing would be "inconvenient".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workable solution, but that's not really elegant so I will leave this unaccepted for a while in hope someone can come up with a better solution.

Removing `ssl_client_certificate` and switching to `ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca` will actually fetch the client certificate, but it will not try to check it so the backend can do its checks autonomously.

My current nginx setup is:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    resolver 127.0.0.1 8.8.8.8;
    set $backend "http://localhost:5000";

    server_name updates.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/server.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/server.key;

    ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;

    location / {
        proxy_connect_timeout   60;
        proxy_read_timeout      60;
        proxy_send_timeout      60;
        proxy_intercept_errors  off;
        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host               $http_host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header        X-Client-Subject   $ssl_client_s_dn;
        proxy_set_header        X-Client-Cert      $ssl_client_cert;
        proxy_pass $backend;
    }
}
```

Backend (a simple python/flask installation) includes:

```
def get_id(headers):
    cer = headers.get('X-Client-Cert')
    with NamedTemporaryFile('w+') as ntf:
        for lin in cer.splitlines():
            ntf.write(lin.strip())
            ntf.write('\n')
        ntf.flush()
        p = run(['openssl', 'verify', '-CAfile', cafile, ntf.name])
    if p.returncode == 0:
        m = search(r'/CN=([~/]+)', headers.get('X-Client-Subject'))
        if m:
            return m.group(1)
    return None
```